# SELECT * Returns no rows but, SELECT Count(*) returns non zero value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I run following queries :

```
a. select * from TABLE_TEMP
```

The query is executed successfully but, no rows are returned. the returned dataset is empty and contains 0 rows. 
The execution plan of this query can be downloaded from :
[Execution Plan Query a](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4OsGTJgg3DhY0k4a3JnWjJRYnk2WVpGQWpsZVN0Zw)

```
b. select count(*) from TABLE_TEMP
```

This query is also executed successfully but, it returns some finite value 
The execution plan of this query can be downloaded from :
[Execution Plan Query b](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4OsGTJgg3DhSjNIc3FOb1NTMlM1ZWRQZ1YydzJVQQ)

Can you provide me any pointers to resolve this issue.

PFB the screenshot:
[image: Weird behavior]

Comment: That is *exactly* the behavior you should expect. The value returned should be 0. Or 1, if you are talking about the "rows affected"

Comment: "Some finite value": Would that be 0?

Comment: No. The no. of rows is greater than 0. screenshot :http://i43.tinypic.com/s0zebb.jpg

Comment: @Abhineet - Can you capture the Actual Execution Plans for those queries and post the XML up somewhere?

Comment: I have uploaded the Actual Execution Plan of the queries.

Comment: Agree with @ta.speot.is - Looks like either the clustered index `PK__airwaybills_hist__3493CFA7` or the NCI `Idx_sender_reference` must be corrupted. Which one of them is correct in your view?

Comment: Very Important: What does your "Messages" tab say for the above screenshot?

Comment: Also: what version of SQL Server?

Comment: @MartinSmith and ta.speot.is : Issue was Solved using repair_rebuild.

Comment: @RBarryYoung : Messages tab does not show any error. The Version of SQL Server is 2005

Comment: @Abhineet: I hope this was not a production database? repair is likely to remove data without notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be suffering from some sort of corruption in your database. Run `DBCC CHECKDB` (or `DBCC CHECKTABLE`) after familiarising yourself with [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx). In particular, the section on index checking with respect to database compatibility levels and:

> In earlier versions of SQL Server, the values for the per-table and per-index row count and page counts can become incorrect. Under certain circumstances, one or more of these values might even become negative. In SQL Server 2005 and later, these values are always maintained correctly. Therefore, databases that are created on SQL Server 2005 and later should never contain incorrect counts; however, databases that are upgraded to SQL Server 2005 and later might.

Comment: The row count never comes from the tables meta-data. It is always counted.

Comment: @usr I feel that what your saying is correct, but is there anything in the documentation to support this? Or is it simply an implementation detail that might change in later versions of SQL Server?

Comment: The row counts referred to in your quote are only used for cardinality estimates when costing plans. Never for answering `COUNT(*)` queries. Not sure there is any documentation explicitly saying this but you can look at the OP's query plans. It is doing a NCI scan feeding into an aggregate operator. Not a look up in the system tables!

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Your query plans confirm this.

Answer (score -1):

Count is Function in SQL it returns Int value i.e. how many records affected.

Comment: Select * query is returning empty dataset.

Comment: I think *SELECT is a statement that retrieves rows from the database and enables the selection of one or many rows or columns from one or many tables in SQL Server* would have been more helpful???